# Using an if statement in function argument when calling

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to use an if statement or similar in function arguments to reduce blocks of code?

```
    if versionid is None:
        s3_response = s3_client.head_object(
              Bucket=bucket
            , Key=key
            )
    else:
        s3_response = s3_client.head_object(
              Bucket=bucket
            , Key=key
            , VersionId=versionid
            )
```

to something like this:

```
        s3_response = s3_client.head_object(
              Bucket=bucket
            , Key=key
            , if versionid is not None: VersionId=versionid
            )
```

Not able to get this working and can't find any examples so assume not possible.

Comment: [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/394809/1258041)

Comment: You can use the conditional operator to choose different values of the argument based on a condition, but not whether to provide the argument or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a statement where an expression is expected. Unless you know what the default value (if any) for the `VersionId` parameter is, you can do something like this:

```
args = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Key': key}
if versionid is not None:
    args['VersionId'] = versionid

s3_response = s3_client.head_object(**args)
```

If you *do* know the appropriate default, you can use the conditional expression:

```
# FOO is whatever the appropriate default is
s3_response = s3_client.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Versionid=FOO if versonid is None else versionid)
```

(Assuming a non-`None` `versionid` will be a truthy value, you can shorten this to `versionid or FOO`, but be aware that `0 or FOO` is `0`, not `FOO`.)

---

You *could* write something like

```
s3_response = s3_client.head_object(
                Bucket=bucket,
                Key=key,
                **({} if versionid is None else {'VersionID': versionid})
              )
```

but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: The first example is perfect here because it requires a string if sending, so None will not work, and I have no default. This is all super useful knowledge, cheers.

Comment: Yeah, if using a `**` parameter, then the only distinction to make may be whether the keyword argument is present or not, not whether it has one value or another.